# Create a dictionary whose keys are month names and values are no. of days in the corresponding month. #program stack

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack

please correct the code.
Create a dictionary whose keys are month names and values are no. of days in the corresponding month. WAP with separate user defined functions to implement the following operations.
(i)push only those names on the stack whose no. of days are 31.
(ii) pop and display the content of the stack.

plzz correct the code
code: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fj3eaa2zXIkwhE6W4apLjmva44hxi51C/edit

Comment: Please [edit] and add the code directly in the question as text.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit] your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [**full text** of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), *all as formatted text in the question itself.* Do not post images of text.

Comment: To do this you'll need to account for the relevant year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you wanted

Edit: Edited the code to meet the new requirements.

(I don't understand what do you mean by 'stack' but you can continue from here)

```
def create_month_day_dict(year, long_only=False):
    months_names = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October',
                    'November', 'December']
    days_in_month = [31, 28 + (year % 4 == 0), 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

    return dict((k, v) for k, v in zip(months_names, days_in_month) if not long_only or v == 31)


print(create_month_day_dict(2022, long_only=True))
print(create_month_day_dict(2024))
```

output:

```
{'January': 31, 'March': 31, 'May': 31, 'July': 31, 'August': 31, 'October': 31, 'December': 31}

{'January': 31, 'February': 29, 'March': 31, 'April': 30, 'May': 31, 'June': 30, 'July': 31, 'August': 31, 'September': 30, 'October': 31, 'November': 30, 'December': 31}
```

Note: also considered the relevant year

Comment: all is write but main work was to to make push and pop function in stack plzz correct thta.

Comment: Do you want to push and pop a month from a list?

What month would you want to push? what if it doesn’t exist

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the year when building a dictionary to help with this problem. The *calendar* module is ideal for this:

```
from calendar import monthrange, month_abbr

def make_dictionary(year):
    d = {'year': year}
    for i in range(1, 13):
        d[month_abbr[i]] = monthrange(year, i)[1]
    return d
    
print(make_dictionary(2024))
```

**Output:**

```
{'year': 2024, 'Jan': 31, 'Feb': 29, 'Mar': 31, 'Apr': 30, 'May': 31, 'Jun': 30, 'Jul': 31, 'Aug': 31, 'Sep': 30, 'Oct': 31, 'Nov': 30, 'Dec': 31}
```

If you want the full (rather than abbreviated) month name then import *month_name* and use that